# Syncfusion Data integration: CRON driven scheduling strategy - @OnScheduled method NullPointerException

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, syncfusion, bigdata

I'm testing **Syncfusion Data Integration Platform** (based on Apache NiFi) and trying to invoke processor by CRON driven scheduling strategy.

I put into "Run Schedule" field this value: `0 19 22 10 7 ? 2017`

But when I start processor I immediately get an error:

```
failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.NullPointerException
```

That errors happens with all processors which I try to run by **CRON driven scheduling strategy**.
Timer driven strategy works ok.
Pure NiFi (without Syncfusion) works ok too.

What is the reason?

From log file:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

...

```
ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.p.standard.GenerateFlowFile GenerateFlowFile[id=347af75d-b2d1-4460-3037-a4ca4fcd25fb] GenerateFlowFile[id=347af75d-b2d1-4460-3037-a4ca4fcd25fb] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.NullPointerException; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30 seconds: java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-07-10 23:17:53,844 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.p.standard.GenerateFlowFile 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingAgent.doSchedule(QuartzSchedulingAgent.java:185) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.AbstractSchedulingAgent.schedule(AbstractSchedulingAgent.java:46) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingAgent.schedule(QuartzSchedulingAgent.java:47) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.StandardProcessScheduler$4.trigger(StandardProcessScheduler.java:311) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1286) ~[na:na]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
2017-07-10 23:17:53,853 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingAgent.doSchedule(QuartzSchedulingAgent.java:185) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.AbstractSchedulingAgent.schedule(AbstractSchedulingAgent.java:46) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingAgent.schedule(QuartzSchedulingAgent.java:47) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.StandardProcessScheduler$4.trigger(StandardProcessScheduler.java:311) ~[na:na]
  at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1286) ~[na:na]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
2017-07-10 23:17:56,058 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.n.p.FlowConfigurationArchiveManager Removing old archive file .\conf\archive\20170710T231701+0600_flow.xml.gz to reduce storage usage. currentSize=508959
2017-07-10 23:17:56,060 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@591cd567 // Another save pending = false
2017-07-10 23:18:00,358 INFO [Data Integration Web Server-16] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Stopping processor: class org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile
2017-07-10 23:18:00,379 WARN [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Failed while shutting down processor GenerateFlowFile[id=347af75d-b2d1-4460-3037-a4ca4fcd25fb]
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your cron expression is **invalid** that may be root cause for error.

What would be meaning for your expression in your cron schedule?

Replace used expression `0 19 22 10 7 ? 2017` with this `0 19 22 10 7 ? * 2017`

You can generate cron expression with help of below website.

http://www.cronmaker.com/

I hope that it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: @mahendra-prabhu Thank you for the answer.
Your solution worked. But I still not understand why my expression is invalid..
My CRON expression works on pure Apache NiFi.. I use this quartz-scheduler tutorial: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html#examples It means starting only once at certain date and time (i.e. 10 July 2017, 10PM-19min-00sec )

Comment: I think if give an invalid cron expression then same error will be shown in pure Nifi also.

Comment: @Bo. Both the expression is valid. Ensure that the entered time and date is forth coming date or not, if the processor scheduled to particular date and to run only once. This expression  "0 19 22 10 7 ? 2017" fires at 10:19 PM on 10th july 2017 and it never schedule again and run only once.But this expression "0 19 22 10 7 ? * 2017" works and the reason is, it fires at 10:19 PM on 10th july during every year. Please find the next scheduled dates below,

1. Tuesday, July 10, 2018 10:19 PM
2. Wednesday, July 10, 2019 10:19 PM
3. Friday, July 10, 2020 10:19 PM

Comment: use the below link to make proper CRON expressions,
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#cronexpressionexamples

Answer (score 1):

The given error may be caused due to two reasons.

1. If the given cron expression is invalid.
2. If the given date is in past.

Here the given expression “0 19 22 10 7 ? 2017” is valid.

Ensure that the entered time and date is forth coming date or not, if the processor scheduled to particular date.

Try this CRON expression “0 15 23 12 7 ? 2017” which fires at 11.15 PM on 12th july 2017 (i.e today).

Please find the few CRON-DRIVEN expression below.

**CRON-DRIVEN Expression 1:**

0 0 13 12 JUL ? 2017
(or)
0 0 13 12 7 ? 2017

**Meaning:**

Fire at 1.00 PM on 12th july 2017

**Next scheduled Dates:**

Run only once.

**CRON-DRIVEN Expression 1:**

0 0 13 12 JUL ? 2017-2020
(or)
0 0 13 12 7 ? 2017-2020

**Meaning:**

Fire at 1.00 PM on 12th july during the years 2017,2018,2019 and 2020.

**Next scheduled Dates:**

•   Wednesday, July 12, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Thursday, July 12, 2018 1:00 PM
•   Friday, July 12, 2019 1:00 PM
•   Sunday, July 12, 2020 1:00 PM

**CRON-DRIVEN Expression 3:**

0 0 13 12 7 ? *
(or)
0 0 13 12 JUL ? *

**Meaning:**

Fire at 1:00 PM on 12th july on every year

**Next scheduled Dates:**

•   Wednesday, July 12, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Thursday, July 12, 2018 1:00 PM
•   Friday, July 12, 2019 1:00 PM
•   Sunday, July 12, 2020 1:00 PM
•   Monday, July 12, 2021 1:00 PM

**CRON-DRIVEN Expression 4:**

0 0 13 * * ? 2017

**Meaning:**

Fire at 1:00 PM every day during the year 2017

**Next scheduled Dates:**

•   Wednesday, July 12, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Thursday, July 13, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Friday, July 14, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Saturday, July 15, 2017 1:00 PM
•   Sunday, July 16, 2017 1:00 PM